# Powershell: how to exclude label from results

Tags: powershell

Just getting started with Powershell and have a quick question.  Trying to run this statement:

`gwmi -query "select Description from Win32_OperatingSystem" | select-object Description`

The results come back as:

```
Description
------------
My PC Name
```

But I just want `MY PC Name`.  What else to I need to add to the statement to remove the label and just get the value?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your output is going through (Format-Default and then) Format-Table, which adds that header. You can get rid of it by specifying `Format-Table -HideTableHeaders` ...

OR ... if you really just want the string, you can use any of these patterns:

```
(gwmi -query "select Description from Win32_OperatingSystem").Description
gwmi -query "select Description from Win32_OperatingSystem" | Select -Expand Description
gwmi -query "select Description from Win32_OperatingSystem" | ForEach{ $_.Description }
```

Comment: Thanks Jaykul, I really appreciate the insight as to why the header gets added in the first place in addition to the solution to my exact problem!